# Dismissing Android Spinner with ArrayAdapter loses item padding

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I have an issue where if I'm using a basic ArrayAdapter to display items in a spinner, all the spacing on those items is lost if I open the spinner, dismiss it by tapping outside of it, then open it again. It appears other attributes like color and such are still kept intact.

Here is how I am creating the spinner:

```
binding.fragmentTypeSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(mContext,
                R.layout.item_simple_spinner,
                typeArray));
```

item_simple_spinner.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_simple_text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorTransparent"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:padding="10dp" />
```

How it looks at first:
[image: How it looks at first]

How it looks after:[image]

I tried with just the basic android spinner item layout as well and still no dice. Has this happened to anyone else before? I searched but couldn't come up with much.

Comment: how do you dismiss your spinner?

Comment: Default handling. Just by tapping outside of it.

Comment: Can you provide a demo app.. This will be a kind of guessing game as we can't reproduce it